# How to make a Dialogflow ChatBot start chat without any user input?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialogflow-es

I have set up a chat bot and it's functioning as expected, it is giving the output as the agent is trained. But I need the Chatbot to initiate the conversation with a welcome note whenever I am opening the app. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // implement your dialog here
});
```

call this inside initState